# How does the case by type work in scala?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros, partialfunction, scala-compiler

I know about case classes, pattern matching, unapply and PartialFunction, but I'm confused about bellow macros snippet.

```
val declarations = weakTypeOf[T].declarations
val methods = declarations.collect { case m: MethodSymbol => m }
```

Scaladoc of MemberScope 
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/#scala.reflect.api.Scopes$MemberScope

Collect method accepts `PartialFunction[Universe.Symbol, B]`
I can't find `unapply` method of `MethodSymbol` and it's also trait not a case class, so in witch code compiler transforms

```
{ case m: MethodSymbol => m }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `MethodSymbol` is not a generic type, the match

```
case m: MethodSymbol => m
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
case m if m.isInstanceOf[MethodSymbol] => m
```

There is absolutely no magic here, and `unapply` machinery is not related to such matches at all. Same thing can easily be done even in Java.